# Facebook PHP SDK not returning a login link

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, sdk

So recently I've begun work on a plugin for wordpress that integrates with facebook, I've never used Facebook's SDK before, but after reading the documentation I felt relatively confident. But I've run into a problem at the oAuth level, my code does not seem to generate a loginUrl, when I look at the source on my plugin's settings page, there is no link visible. The code in question is below:

**oAuth.php**

```
<?php

include_once('src/facebook.php');

$fbconfig = array(
    'appId' => 'app1d',
    'secret' => '53cr3t',
    'cookie' => true  
              );

$facebook = new Facebook($fbconfig);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
array(
    'scope' => 'offline_access, user_events',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/mad/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=facebook_event_options'
    )
);

?>
```

**And here's the code on the menu page that isn't working**

This code is on another page, I've included oAuth.php on this page.

```
       echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '"><img src="' . plugins_url('EventsList/images/connect.png') . '" class="fbConnect"></a>';
```

It's probably something that's so simple I haven't noticed it, any help would greatly be appreciated :)

Comment: `there is no link visible` is not equal to `PHP SDK not returning a login link`. What if you `var_dump($loginUrl);` right after the assignment?

Comment: I get a null value returned on the other page, but when I do a var_dump($loginUrl) on the oAuth.php page I get the URL, I've tried moving all code to the menu page but that doesn't seem to work either :S

Comment: if it works on one page and doesn't on another - then *you* must be doing something wrong

Comment: Ok it was something embarrassingly simple, I was using the $loginUrl variable inside a function on the other page, so all I had to do was declare that variable global inside the function, thank you anyway zerkms for pointing out the var_dump method that let me narrow it down.

Comment: you'd better wrapped all the code into a function or class and call them, instead of global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the variables scope

Though you'd better wrapped all your retrieving link code into a function and call it, instead of using global variables